# Como pegar o conteúdo de uma HTML Table e converter em uma C# List<>?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Tenho uma tabela `html` que é criada dinamicamente pelo usuário. Preciso pegar todos os dados inseridos por ele na tabela e gerar uma List para poder salvar posteriormente em um banco de dados.

Seguem dados do projeto:

```
public class Procedimento
{
    string cnes;
    string cbo;
    string profissional;
    string procedimento;
    int idade;
    int quant;
}
```

Código da tabela:

```
<table id="tabelaProducao">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;">CNES</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">CBO</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Profissional</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Procedimento</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Idade</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Quant</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7559267</td>
            <td>352210</td>
            <td>RENATA CARVALHO DA SILVA</td>
            <td>0101050062</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7559267</td>
            <td>352210</td>
            <td>JOSE SILVANIR DA ROCHA</td>
            <td>0101050062</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Creio que usando Json deve funcionar, mas ainda não sei como fazer.

Os dados serão recebidos via `POST` e o `Controller` irá ler esses dados e salvar no banco.

Comment: como as informações são enviadas ao backend? como o backend captura essas informações? Forneça mais detalhes, por favor.

Comment: Minha ideia é criar um array que possa ser enviado para o Controller transformá-lo na List e salvar no banco de dados. Não sei se estou sendo claro, é que estou aprendendo MVC e Json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coloque classes em cada coluna, chame cada linha e encapsule pela classe.

HTML:

```
<table id="tabelaProducao">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;">CNES</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">CBO</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Profissional</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Procedimento</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Idade</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Quant</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="cnes">7559267</td>
            <td class="cbo">352210</td>
            <td class="profissional">JOSE SILVANIR DA ROCHA</td>
            <td class="procedimento">0101050062</td>
            <td class="idade">0</td>
            <td class="quant">18</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
function encapsularDadosTabela() {
    var listaTabela = [];
    $.each($("#tabelaProducao > tbody > tr"), function (index, value) {
        var linhaTabela = $(this);
        var itemTabela = {
            cnes: linhaTabela.find(".cnes").val(),
            cbo: linhaTabela.find(".cbo").val(),
            profissional: linhaTabela.find(".profissional").val(),
            procedimento: linhaTabela.find(".procedimento").val(),
            idade: linhaTabela.find(".idade").val(),
            quant: linhaTabela.find(".quant").val()
        };
        listaTabela.push(itemTabela);
    });
    return listaTabela;
};

function chamadaAjax(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "URLAQUI",
        type: "POST",
        data: { model: encapsularDadosTabela() },
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
};
```

CONTROLLER:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SuaAction(IEnumerable<Procedimento> model)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Ótimo Ayrton, exatamente isso que estou precisando. Na linha `data: { model: encapsularDadosTabela() }`, sei que no meu `Controller` irei configurar o mesmo para receber o parâmetro `model`, esse parâmetro deve ser de que tipo?

Comment: Eita, na hora que perguntei, você alterou lá. Obrigado.

Comment: Editei meu comentário acima mostrando como você deve encapsular. Importante que você saiba que o parâmetro "model" na requisição Ajax deve ter o mesmo nome do seu parâmetro que vai receber a requisição, ou seja, neste caso deve ser model também.

Comment: Certo, estou fazendo uns testes aqui, mas creio que dará certo